# how to select a string attribute from a table in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sqlite

I have a method which is supposed to return a `PatientDetails` object when I insert an unique `nric` as the parameter. This doesn't work. However when I changed this method to accept `int age` instead of `NSString * nric`, it worked.

Is there something wrong with my syntax `"WHERE ic = %s"` cause it seems wierd. I have googled 2 days on this and cannot find a solution.

Please help as I am a newbie.

```
- (PatientDetails *)patientDetails:(NSString *)nric {
    PatientDetails *retval = nil;
    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT ic, district, age, race, referralSource, DMRelatedAdmin, postalCode FROM patientInfo WHERE ic = %s" , nric];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
```

Comment: Please put the code in code environment. And please provide more code. Where is query used? And where does statement come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%s` denotes the standard C string. In order to use `NSString` objects as the argument, you need to use the object notation `%@`.

`WHERE ic = '%@'`

Comment: Wow... Thank you so much! U saved me a hell lot of time! grateful!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the format specifier for Objective-C strings is `%@`. So it should be,

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT ic, district, age, race, referralSource, DMRelatedAdmin, postalCode FROM patientInfo WHERE ic = %@" , nric];
```

Comment: hey Deepak.. thanks so much for helping!! but i think i needed this ic = '%@' from Simon..

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot that about that quote focussing on the format specifier. You should select Simon's answer as the right one. Tick mark on the left of his answer.